# Create An Observable From An Edit Text

Tags: java, android, rx-android, android-databinding, rx-java2

I am using android data binding and i want to create an observable from the edit text data so i can perform operations on it using rxjava.
This is my code.

The XML

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.getUsername}"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edit_top"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_white_24px"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_white_24px"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            app:layout_heightPercent="10%" />
```

The ViewModel Class

```
 public TextWatcher getUsername() {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.i("username", s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

I have 3 such edit texts on which i want to use the combinelatest operator of rx java for form validations.How exactly do i go about implementing rx java in this scenario?

Comment: Can you try to instantiate the`TextWatcher` for itself and not through a getter? Something like `public TextWatchern textWatcher = new TextWatcher(...)` and `  android:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.textWatcher}"`. I think you can also create a public getter for the `TextWatcher` and make the field itself `private`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). This example could help you.

```
//Validate username field
Observable<Boolean> usernameObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(usernameEditText)
                .map(username -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(username) && Validators.validateUsername(username.toString())).skip(1);

//Validate password field
Observable<CharSequence> passwordObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(passwordEditText).skip(1);

//Validate confirm password field
Observable<CharSequence> confirmPasswordObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(confirmPasswordEditText)
                .skip(1);

//Validate password matches field
Observable<Boolean> passwordMatcherObservable = Observable.combineLatest(passwordObservable, confirmPasswordObservable,
                (password, confirmPassword) -> password.toString().equals(confirmPassword.toString())).skip(1);

Observable.combineLatest(passwordMatcherObservable, usernameObservable,
                (passwordMatch, isUsernameValid) -> passwordMatch && isUsernameValid)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribe(valid -> createAccountBtn.setEnabled(valid));
```

Comment: why you put `.skip(1)` ?

Comment: The first time the fields are empty, so I got a InputTextLayout and I want to avoid the first validation.

Comment: I have checked later, they say also that because BeforeTextChange event gets called for the current existing text of the EditText.